# Extract significant near future local events exact location and time using Facebook Graph Search api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, events, time, location

I am looking for a way to extract significant (number of attendees > threshold) near future (within the next week) local events exact location and time using Facebook Graph Search api.

If local cannot be done,  i could just specify a city (Athens, GR for example) instead.

It would be absolutely great if the info could be extracted with one query, but i think this is too much to hope for.

What i have tried so far is:

1. search?fields=location,events,name&limit=300&q=athens&type=place

This produces a set of events with name relative to "athens" as well as exact location, but not the time or number of attendees or event name.

2. {event_ID}?fields=attending.limit(1).summary(true)

This produces the number of attendees for a specific event_ID.

The total number of significant (let's assume more than 300 attendees) event for a week's span in Athens, GR should not be very high, therefore i could manually query the API as a last resort solution.

Does anyone have any idea if/how what i am asking can be achieved?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this just in one query although you can probably batch some requests (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests).

What I would do is:

1. Geo query to place: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#search

   GET graph.facebook.com
     /search?
     q=coffee&
     type=place&
     center=37.76,-122.427&
     distance=1000
2. Get the page_id and query for public events (batch): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events
3. Get attendants for those events (batch): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event/attending

I hope it helps.